TF237201: Cannot add a new link because one of the work items being linked will exceed the 1000 link limit
My team was using Azure DevOps Service and encountered this error:
TF237201: Cannot add a new link because one of the work items being linked will exceed the 1000 link limit. Remove links from that item and try saving again. For more details, please refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858636.`

I follow the suggested article but it's for the local SQL database, not Azure DevOps Service.
Can anybody help me to raise the limit of link to work items?
Thanh
My team was creating the Work Items and Links to them. And then we got the error.

According to this document of Azure DevOps Services, the limit for work item links assigned to a work item is 1000.
As of now, I am afraid this is a hard limit and cannot be increased. This limit is designed to protect against SQL CPU spikes that can occur with the update work item API, which traverses the entire link tree to prevent loops while adding a unidirectional link.
Best practices are not to create a large number of links for a single work item. You might give a try to report a feature request to increase this default limit here; still we cannot guarantee that the request can be approved or released in the near future. Anyway, SO is not the right place the communicate with product engineering team.
